# jQuery - clicking 1 div and change class on 2 divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 divs named `yellowUp` with up arrows as background images.

As it is now, when I click on a `yellowUp` div, only the clicked div changes class. How do I make both divs change class on click?

**HTML**

```
<div class="yellowUp"></div>

<div class="yellowUp"></div>

<div id="contentContainer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.yellowUp {
   background-image: url(../images/arrow-up.png);
}

.clicked {
    background-image: url(../images/arrow-down.png);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".yellowUp").click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( $(this).hasClass("clicked") ) {
        $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200);                       
    } else {
        $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"-300px"}, 200);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want both `.yellowUp` divs to have the `.clicked` class when 1 is clicked, then instead of doing `$(this).toggleClass("clicked");` just select the class instead.

**jQuery**

```
$(".yellowUp").toggleClass("clicked");
```

---

```js
$(".yellowUp").click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( $(this).hasClass("clicked") ) {
        $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200);                       
    } else {
        $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"-300px"}, 200);
    }
    $('.yellowUp').toggleClass("clicked");
    return false;
});
```

```css
.yellowUp {
   color: blue;
}

.clicked {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="yellowUp">Hi</div>

<div class="yellowUp">Hi</div>

<div id="contentContainer">BLah</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because you only change the class of the clicked object.
instead, use  :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.yellowUp').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.yellowUp').each(function($key, $index) {
         if ( $(this).hasClass("clicked") ) {
            $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200);                       
        } else {
            $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"-300px"}, 200);
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
    });
});
});
```

In the previous code we parse each element with the class yellowUp to toggle clicked.

hopes it helps !

- Nic

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this toggleClass to select ".yellowUp"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nic,

I went with this really simple option (to me at least):

```
$(".yellowUp").click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( $(this).hasClass("clicked") ) {
        $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200); 
        $(".yellowUp").css("background-image", "url(images/arrow-up.png)");                      
    } else {
        $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"100px"}, 200);
        $(".yellowUp").css("background-image", "url(images/arrow-down.png)");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
    return false;
});
```

I just added a css background image change for each condition.